# Finding initial value of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Given,
$$ mdv/dt = mg - kv $$

Question is:

> Find the velocity $v(t)$ that satisfies this initial value problem.
>   Also, by letting $t$ approach positive infinity, determine the terminal velocity of the ball.

I first separated the equation and got
$$ dv/dt = g - k/mv $$

I have no clue how to approach this question. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are we to assume that the variables are $v$ (dependent) and $t$ (independent) and that $m$, $g$, and $k$ are real constants? And is the equation $m\frac{dv}{dt}=mgkv$? If so, why doesn't the $m$ immediately cancel?

Answer (score 1):

then terminal velocity is the constant velocity $v_\infty$ which is given by $$kv_\infty = m \, g \to v_\infty = \frac{mg} v.$$ we can now write the differential equation as $$\frac{dv }{dt} = \frac k m(v_\infty - v) \to \frac{dv}{v_\infty - v} = \frac k mdt$$ and can ve integrated to yield $$\ln(v_\infty - v) = -\frac k mt + \ln C \to v = v_\infty - Ce^{-kt/m}$$

Comment: how is terminal velocity is the constant velocity V∞ = g/km ?

Comment: @SteveKim, how are you going to terminal velocity?

Comment: i have no idea ... or is v∞ = g/km the only formula?

Comment: @SteveKim, sorry for the typos. hopefully everything is is fixed  now.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=g-k/m·v$. Then 
$$
u'=-\frac km ·v'=-\frac km·u
$$
which is the well known equation for exponential growth resp. decay.

Answer (score 0):

$$v'+\frac kmv=g$$ is a first order ordinary linear equation of constant coefficients.

You can use the integrand factor $e^{\frac kmt}$ to get

$$(ve^{\frac km})'=ge^{\frac kmt},$$
and
$$ve^{\frac kmt}=\frac{mg}ke^{\frac kmt}+C.$$

or
$$v=\frac{mg}k+Ce^{-\frac kmt}.$$

The integration constant is found from

$$v_0=\frac{mg}k+C.$$

The speed at infinity is more directly obtained by setting $v'=0$ (steady regime), so that

$$v=\frac{mg}k.$$

Comment: Setting $v'=0$ happens to work for this particular example, but it is not a general approach. Finding the extrema of the velocity is not the same as finding the terminal velocity.